# Error using "npm" command on Node version 14.X Error: 'timers/promises' module not found

Tags: node.js, npm

When I try to run any `npm` command, I get the following error:

```
 C:\Users\sindh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\es6\validate-engines.js:31
    throw err
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'timers/promises'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\sindh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\agent\lib\util.js
- C:\Users\sindh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\agent\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\sindh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\remote.js
- C:\Users\sindh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-  happen\lib\cache\entry.js
- C:\Users\sindh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch- happen\lib\cache\index.js
- C:\Users\sindh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\fetch.js
- C:\Users\sindh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\sindh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\sindh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\replace-info.js
- C:\Users\sindh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-message.js
- C:\Users\sindh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\exit-handler.js
- C:\Users\sindh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli-entry.js
- C:\Users\sindh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
- C:\Users\sindh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
at Object.<anonymous>    (C:\Users\sindh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\agent\lib\util.js:3:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\sindh\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\@npmcli\\agent\\lib\\util.js',\]
```

Not sure why this is happening and how to resolve it since I wasn't previously running into this issue. I tried using npm to update my node version to the latest one but this also fails with the same error message

Comment: `node:timers/promises` is added in v15 check your node version

Comment: My node version is 14 as stated in the problem description and I am unable to update it to the latest one since npm update also expects the timers/promises module to be there

Answer (score 0):

`node:timers/promises` is added in v15.

you don't have to update `npm` to update node. Use `nvm` to update properly.

If you don't have `nvm` installed [Look at this](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md)

Follow this steps:

1. Install latest stable version

   ```
   nvm install --lts
   ```
2. Still you only installed but the global node version is not changed, to do that

   ```
   nvm alias default node
   ```